# Hoops in The Book of All Skies

Tags: greg-egan

I'm confused about Greg Egan's ["The Book of All Skies"](https://www.gregegan.net/ALLSKIES/AllSkies.html).

I am pretty sure about the following:

- The worlds form a looping sequence. You can go from world 2 to world 1 or world 3. Just two neighbors for each world. This is supported by the cover art and by Sadema and Celema being the two ends of the known space. (At the start.)
- There are two Hoops on each world. They are two vertical disks some distance apart. This is supported, among others, by this description in chapter 25:

  > “And it’s coming up to the ideal time to enter through the western Hoop: any earlier, and we’d have to cool our heels waiting for sunset to reach the eastern Hoop; any later and we’d risk stepping out into sunshine. Go now, and we can drive from Hoop to Hoop at an ordinary pace, with no delays – but even if we get held up for some reason, it’s only the way back that will be blocked. The way out will stay open for half a year.”
- Each Hoop has two sides. They are described as vertical disks. Both sides are generally accessible.

With two Hoops and two sides per Hoop, we have four portals in each world. But they lead to only two neighboring worlds. How is that?

- Do both sides of each Hoop lead to the same world? If so, how can Del chase Orsino on foot through multiple worlds via the "ring road"? It goes in a circle around a hill. I read it as going to the other side of the same Hoop.
- Do the two sides of each Hoop lead to different worlds? If so, why do they sometimes travel from one Hoop to the other?

Sometimes they travel around the same Hoop multiple times and also switch to the other Hoop in a complicated pattern, as in chapter 9:

> They were in the sixth circuit of their second traversal of the western Hoop when Del noticed the world finally growing smaller. [...] The eastern Hoop had also stood at a similar angle, for the five circuits they’d completed before coming west again.

Going just repeatedly around the same Hoop is considered ridiculous. From chapter 6:

> “If we stayed at this edge, and just circled it until we hit the nub ... ?” she joked.
>
> “We could try the same measurements,” Montano conceded. “And see if the gap was small enough to bridge. But that would be a lot of work, for no reward.”

How is that a joke? Why *not* just circle the edge? And how does that answer help? Circling the same edge seems way less work than going criss-cross! And "no reward"? Why?

The [accompanying material](https://www.gregegan.net/ALLSKIES/01/Gravity.html) on Greg Egan's website doesn't clear up this matter. It says:

> If we ignore one of the Hoops and just consider the effects of a single one, the multiply connected space it gives access to comprises a certain number N of copies of ordinary space, numbered 1, 2, 3, ..., N, which have been spliced together as follows: if you pass through the Hoop in space i in one direction, you emerge from the Hoop in space i+1, and if you pass through the Hoop in space i in the other direction, you emerge from the Hoop in space i–1. Whenever this recipe suggests you would go higher than space N or lower than space 1, you simply wrap around to space 1 or space N respectively.

How is that different from the setup in the novel? What does the second Hoop do?

Comment: Maybe the second hoop is just to get a more complicated topology (and more complicated need for route-planning) than if there was just one hoop? W/ only one hoop, you'd just have a linear series of lands/skies. I'm not sure how to interpret Montano's comment that you quoted, but it could be that while repeatedly circling one edge would take you to *some* nub, it wasn't the route to the particular nub that Montano's sister had already visited and taken the detailed gravitational measurements of, and maybe the small gap suggested by the measurements at the nub she visited was a rare phenomenon.

Comment: Has she visited Celema? I can't find that in the text now. But I found something else! I think Celema lies on the "straight line" from Sadema. That is if you go through the same Hoop repeatedly from Sadema, the nub you will reach is Celema. (I've added the quote to my answer.)

Comment: Ah you're right, I was misremembering and thinking Natasha had made measurements, but it looks like she'd only done theoretical calculations. So it's probably the reason you mention, that he hopes traveling the same hoop repeatedly is a "circle"-like path that will take one to the other side of the mountains which obstruct the path through one hoop in Sadema. This is supported by Montano's line "If the path joins up with its own beginning, it's no different from any other circle. You can't block a circle at one point; you can always avoid the obstruction by going the other way around."

Answer (score 4):

My first "fact" is wrong. Each world has 4 neighbors. In the book we only hear about one "nub", Celema, and its counterpart on the other side. But Greg Egan [says](https://twitter.com/gregeganSF/status/1440087818341011460):

> Yes, there are many other pairs of nubs.

The cover is also misleading. Greg Egan [says](https://twitter.com/gregeganSF/status/1437754689018216451):

> Yes! The actual space is more complicated, of course, being 3D, but that captures a sense of how the view of the sky behaves locally.

Other than being 4-regular and 2-connected (at least), it's hard to say more about the graph of connected worlds. Sadema appears to be unique. From chapter 3:

> “And since Sadema was the only land whose terrain appeared to render one of the Hoops impassable, where else could the crucial path lie, but through those formidable mountains?”

So why did Montano pick Celema and not a nub that's easier to reach. Like the one Del "jokes" about. Would the path through that nub not lead to the other side of Sadema?

Looks like Montano expects that a "straight line" will form a loop.

> Del frowned. “So you travel to the nub at Celema, and then keep going – somehow – through the void. In the hope that, eventually ... you end up where you began?”
>
> Montano said, “Not literally, though – not if you began somewhere like Thena. We need to imagine a traveler who does nothing but go round and round the same part of the same Hoop.”

If you go through the same Hoop repeatedly from Sadema until you reach a nub, that nub is Celema!